# $T_n \rightarrow T$ strongly implies $P(T_n) \rightarrow P(T)$ strongly

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

$T_n$ is a sequence of uniformly bounded operators between two Banach spaces that converges strongly to $T$. If $P$ is a polynomial then $P(T_n)$ converges strongly to $P(T)$.

To prove that, I tried use the fact that $\|T_n x-Tx\|$ goes to $0$ when $n$ goes to $\infty$ to show that $\|T_n ^kx-T^kx\|$ goes $0$ when $n$ goes to $\infty$ for all $k$. My attemps were unseccessful. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you drop the assumption of uniform boundedness and replace it just with boundedness as consequence of the uniform boundedness principle?
Alternatively you could drop the completeness assumption.

Comment: "between two Banach spaces" won't work if you are trying to form polynomials in $T_n$. These need to be operators on a single Banach space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that multiplication has this property.  That is: if $B_n \to B$ and $A_n \to A$ are uniformly bounded sequences (in fact, it suffices to have only one be uniformly bounded so long as both limits are bounded), then $A_nB_n \to AB$.  To see that this is the case, note that
$$
\|A_nB_n - AB\| \leq\\
\|A_nB_n - A_n B\| + \|A_n B - AB\| \leq\\
\|A_n\| \cdot \|B_n - B\| + \|B \| \cdot \|A_n - A\|
$$
With that, note that $T_n^k = T_n \cdot T_n^{k-1}$.